# MySQL Query to fetch count of a same successive two rows based on a column value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I need a sql query which will fetch me the count of unique possible combination of a value a to b of col3 based on the col2 value.
Here in the below table the value a to b is there twice(2 to 3 for col1-1 and 2 to 3 for col1-2).Similarly I need the count of such possible a to b fields as they appear successively in the table(which we can identify from col2-2,3)

I have the following table:

```
      col1   col2   col3    
       1       2      a    
       1       3      b
       1       4      c
       2       2      a
       2       3      b
       2       4      c

Output:

f1  f2  count
a   b    2
b   c    2
```

Here **col1+col2** is the primary key and the query should be generic for n no of possible successive combination.

Comment: What have you done so far? Are you getting any error?

Comment: [ask] and mcve] could be useful to improve your question. Also, do you need a solution for Oracle, MySQL or both?

Comment: I am trying to figure out the query using group by, but finding it difficult to create one.
I am still to compose one.

Comment: MySql will work, I just need the idea of creating such query.

Comment: @Nitish I got the answer for my query, thanks for your positive response.

Comment: @Avinash: Thank you informing me. I see that you have got a solution yourself, which is great. However you need to have a look at the Stackoverflow policies about how to ask a question as suggested by Aleksej. Please also note that I have not downvoted your question.

Comment: @Nitish yes I was unaware of that policy, had a look at that, will follow that in future...thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking into possibilities of finding the solution to my problem, I got one by myself...

Below is the query to get the desired output which I wanted, was pretty straight forward.

```
select a.col3 f1,
b.col3 f2,
count(*) count  
from testTable b,testTable a
where 
a.col2 = b.col2 -1
and a.col1 = b.col1
group by ev1,ev2;
```